# Optimizing query to get entire row where one field is the maximum for a group

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, myisam

I have a table with a schema like, say,

```
EventTime   DATETIME(6),
EventType   VARCHAR(20),
Number1     INT,
Number2     INT,
Number3     INT,
...
```

There are an unimaginably large number of rows in this table, but for the sake of this query I'm only interested in, say, a few thousand of them that are between two given values of `EventTime`.  There's an index on `EventTime`, and if I just do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EventTime >= time1 and EventTime <= time2;
```

Then it's able to return the relevant rows near-instantaneously.

Out of the rows in this time window, I want to extract precisely those where `Number1` is the largest for any row with that `EventType`.  So in other words I want to do something equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT EventType, MAX(Number1) as max_Number1
   FROM table
   WHERE EventTime >= time1 AND EventTime <= time2
   GROUP BY EventType) AS a
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM table
   WHERE EventTime >= time1 AND EventTime <= time2) AS b
  ON a.EventType = b.EventType AND a.max_Number1 = b.Number1)
```

This seems like it should work just fine -- I can run each of the subqueries, namely

```
SELECT EventType, MAX(Number1) as max_Number1
FROM table
WHERE EventTime >= time1 AND EventTime <= time2
GROUP BY EventType;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE EventTime >= time1 AND EventTime <= time2;
```

virtually instantaneously, so at this point it shouldn't be too hard to produce the desired results: the database can sort or index the results of both subquery by `EventType` and then just match things up.

However, when I actually run this it takes *forever*.  I don't know how long, because I've never let it complete, but it takes way longer than it would for me to just manually pull the results of both queries and do the merge elsewhere.

**Questions:**

1. Why is it taking so long?  What is the database engine doing?
2. Is there a way to write this is a query in such a way that it will perform reasonably?
3. If not, can I write it as a stored procedure somehow?

Difficulty: As this table has tens of billions of rows it would be quite costly to add any further indices to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually are already pretty close to a good query. The main drawback of yours is likely the LEFT JOIN on selecting all from `table` in the time frame. Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
table b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EventType, MAX(Number1) as max_Number1
    FROM table
    WHERE EventTime >= time1 AND EventTime <= time2
    GROUP BY EventType
) AS a
ON a.EventType = b.EventType
AND a.max_Number1 = b.Number1
WHERE b.EventTime >= time1 AND b.EventTime <= time2
```

Ideally, this would be accompanied by an index `(EventType,EventTime)`. Please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` in your question, so we can see what indexes you currently have. We may be able to tweak an existing one, or help you drop unneeded ones, to permit adding this new index.

Disclaimer: My experience is pretty exclusively in MySQL and InnoDB, but I think this should still be helpful for MariaDB and MyISAM.

Comment: I'll try this when I get a chance -- currently respinding from my cellphone.  Can you say a bit about *why* the left join is a problem and why this should be an improvement?

Comment: A LEFT JOIN is not the problem itself, but rather the fact that you wrote it is a `(SELECT ... )` join, which tends to optimize poorly, as it will tend to result in a temp table to hold those intermediate results, and without any indexes to use on that temp table.

Comment: Okay, so I tried this once I got to a computer and it runs in about half a second.  That'll do!

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for books, lectures, etc. where I could learn about things like this?

Comment: The manual is a good resource to start with. Here is the page describing the query structure I used for this problem: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html Understanding indexes helps a lot too. If someone asked you "what does an index do?" and you reply with "it speeds up queries" instead of "it makes a copy of the data, making searching on the columns that copy has easier" then take some time researching indexes too. I don't know what you do and don't know already, so just read a lot. The [query-optimization] tag here has many helpful answers.

Comment: In short, the best recommendation I can give is how I learned: Do stuff, research when and ask questions (like you did here), learn to think like the optimizer thinks. This particular query is extremely common in the work I do, which is why I was able to quickly suggest the answer that I did. It was years ago that I first found that solution I linked from the documentation, but I still remember it and, as you can see, it comes in use to share with others.

Comment: Followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429880/optimizing-query-that-looks-at-a-specific-time-window-each-day