# Optimizing query that looks at a specific time window each day

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, myisam

This is a followup to my previous question

[Optimizing query to get entire row where one field is the maximum for a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414269/optimizing-query-to-get-entire-row-where-one-field-is-the-maximum-for-a-group)

I'll change the names from what I used there to make them a little more memorable, but these don't represent my actual use-case (so don't estimate the number of records from them).

I have a table with a schema like this:

```
OrderTime           DATETIME(6),
Customer            VARCHAR(50),
DrinkPrice          DECIMAL,
Bartender           VARCHAR(50),
TimeToPrepareDrink  TIME(6),
...
```

I'd like to extract the rows from the table representing each customer's most expensive drink order during happy hour (3 PM - 6 PM) each day.  So for instance I'd want results like

```
Date   | Customer | OrderTime   | MaxPrice   | Bartender | ...
-------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----
1/1/18 |  Alice   | 1/1/18 3:45 | 13.15      | Jane      | ...
1/1/18 |  Bob     | 1/1/18 5:12 |  9.08      | Jane      | ...
1/1/18 |  Carol   | 1/1/18 4:45 | 20.00      | Tarzan    | ...
1/2/18 |  Alice   | 1/2/18 3:45 | 13.15      | Jane      | ...
1/2/18 |  Bob     | 1/2/18 5:57 |  6.00      | Tarzan    | ...
1/2/18 |  Carol   | 1/2/18 3:13 |  6.00      | Tarzan    | ...
 ...
```

The table has an index on `OrderTime`, and contains tens of billions of records.  (My customers are heavy drinkers).

Thanks to the previous question I'm able to extract this for a specific day pretty easily.  I can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM orders b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Customer, MAX(DrinkPrice) as MaxPrice
    FROM orders
    WHERE OrderTime >= '2018-01-01 15:00' 
      AND OrderTime <= '2018-01-01 18:00'
    GROUP BY Customer
) AS a
ON a.Customer = b.Customer
AND a.MaxPrice = b.DrinkPrice
WHERE b.OrderTime >= '2018-01-01 15:00'
  AND b.OrderTime <= '2018-01-01 18:00';
```

This query runs in less than a second.  The explain plan looks like this:

```
+---+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id| select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key        | ref                | Extra                                                  |
+---+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | PRIMARY     | b          | range | OrderTime     | OrderTime  | NULL               | Using index condition                                  |
| 1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref   | key0          | key0       | b.Customer,b.Price |                                                        |
| 2 | DERIVED     | orders     | range | OrderTime     | OrderTime  | NULL               | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+---+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can also get the information about the relevant rows for my query:

```
SELECT Date, Customer, MAX(DrinkPrice) AS MaxPrice
FROM
        orders
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT '2018-01-01' AS Date 
         UNION
         SELECT '2018-01-02' AS Date) dates
WHERE   OrderTime >= TIMESTAMP(Date, '15:00:00')
AND OrderTime <= TIMESTAMP(Date, '18:00:00')
GROUP BY Date, Customer
 HAVING MaxPrice > 0;
```

This query also runs in less than a second.  Here's how its explain plan looks:

```
+------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | ref  | Extra                                          |
+------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | orders     | ALL  | OrderTime     | NULL | NULL | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
|    2 | DERIVED      | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL | No tables used                                 |
|    3 | UNION        | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL | No tables used                                 |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL |                                                |
+------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem now is retrieving the remaining fields from the table.  I tried adapting the trick from before, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM
        orders a
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT Date, Customer, MAX(DrinkPrice) AS MaxPrice
        FROM
                orders
            INNER JOIN
                (SELECT '2018-01-01' AS Date
                 UNION
                 SELECT '2018-01-02' AS Date) dates
        WHERE   OrderTime >= TIMESTAMP(Date, '15:00:00')
            AND OrderTime <= TIMESTAMP(Date, '18:00:00')
        GROUP BY Date, Customer
        HAVING MaxPrice > 0) b
    ON     a.OrderTime >= TIMESTAMP(b.Date, '15:00:00')
       AND a.OrderTime <= TIMESTAMP(b.Date, '18:00:00')
       AND a.Customer = b.Customer;
```

However, for reasons I don't understand, the database chooses to execute this in a way that takes forever.  Explain plan:

```
+------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | ref        | Extra                                          |
+------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a          | ALL  | OrderTime     | NULL | NULL       |                                                |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ref  | key0          | key0 | a.Customer | Using where                                    |
|    2 | DERIVED      | <derived3> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL       | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|    2 | DERIVED      | orders     | ALL  | OrderTime     | NULL | NULL       | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
|    3 | DERIVED      | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL       | No tables used                                 |
|    4 | UNION        | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL       | No tables used                                 |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union3,4> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL       |                                                |
+------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

**Questions:**

1. What is going on here?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that your actual query may have more than just 2 dates UNIONed together? That it may contain an arbitrary number of dates?

Comment: Yeah, maybe a few years' worth. So long as the performance is O(n) in the number of dates it's no problem, because the query fetching the information for a single date runs in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Basically I just need to know how to force it to do the join as "range checked by record."  I know the performance would be acceptable in that case.

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: Looks like 10.1, why?

Comment: I'm looking into solutions for your query, and some depend on the version. Can you please provide the EXPLAIN plans for each query in your question. Simply add `EXPLAIN ` to the start of each query to get the EXPLAIN plans.

Comment: @WillemRenzema; Added to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders` to your question as well. You can replace the "I have a table with a schema like this:" section in your question with that output. I'll use this new information to understand the indexes used in your EXPLAIN info better.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury - the "Rows" column has been removed?  It often provides useful information.  Please put it back in.

Answer (score 0):

The task seems to be a "groupwise-max" problem.  Here's one approach, involving only 2 'queries' (the inner one is called a "derived table").

```
SELECT  x.OrderDate, x.Customer, b.OrderTime,
        x.MaxPrice, b.Bartender
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  DATE(OrderTime) AS OrderDate,
                Customer,
                Max(Price) AS MaxPrice
            FROM  tbl
            WHERE  TIME(OrderTime) BETWEEN '15:00' AND '18:00'
            GROUP BY  OrderDate, Customer 
    ) AS x
    JOIN  tbl AS b
       ON  b.OrderDate = X.OrderDate
      AND  b.customer = x.Customer
      AND  b.Price = x.MaxPrice
    WHERE  TIME(b.OrderTime) BETWEEN '15:00' AND '18:00'
    ORDER BY  x.OrderDate, x.Customer
```

Desirable index:

```
INDEX(Customer, Price)
```

(There's no good reason to be using MyISAM.)

**Billions of new rows per day**

This adds new wrinkles.  That's upwards of a terabyte of additional disk space needed each and every day?

Is it possible to summarize the data?  The goal here is to add summary info as the new data comes in, and never have to re-scan the billions of old data.  This *may* also let you remove all the secondary indexes on the Fact table.

Normalization will help shrink the table size, hence speeding up the queries.  `Bartender` and `Customer` are prime candidates for such -- perhaps a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes; 65K values) for the former and `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes, 16M) for the latter.  That would probably shrink by 50% the 5 columns you currently show.  You may get a 2x speedup on many operations after normalizing.

Normalization is best done by 'staging' the data -- Load the data into a temporary table, normalize within it, summarize it, *then* copy into the main Fact table.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Before getting back to the question of optimizing the one query, we need to see the schema, the data flow, whether things can be normalized, whether summary tables can be effective, etc.  I would hope to have the 'answer' for the query to be mostly digested in a summary table.  Sometimes this leads to a 10x speedup.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any storage engine other than MyISAM that could handle bulk inserts at an acceptable speed, nor could I find one that had an acceptable footprint on disk.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury - How are you doing the bulk inserts?  Please provide the entire `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there could be things in the schema that slow down bulk inserts?  Do you need to do bulk insert more than once?

Comment: Each day, I bulk insert a few billion records into this table.  I'm translating all the field names manually here, but literally the only thing you'd see in the SHOW CREATE TABLE is that there's an index on OrderTime.  I can't afford the disk space to add another index.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury - More than 1,000,000,000 new rows per day?  Do you also delete some rows?  Please discuss more of the details -- you are into the realm of how to shovel large amounts of data around.  We need to address that _before_ (or maybe at the same time as) we tackle the query optimization.

Comment: Yes, more than a billion new rows a day.  No, data is never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the rows from the table representing each customer's most expensive drink order during happy hour (3 PM - 6 PM) each day I would use `row_number() over()` within a `case expression` evaluating the hour of day, like this:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    Date      DATE 
>   ,Customer  VARCHAR(10)
>   ,OrderTime DATETIME 
>   ,MaxPrice  NUMERIC(12,2)
>   ,Bartender VARCHAR(11)
> );
> ```

note changes were made to OrderTime

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable(Date,Customer,OrderTime,MaxPrice,Bartender) 
> VALUES 
>   ('1/1/18','Alice','1/1/18 13:45',13.15,'Jane')
> , ('1/1/18','Bob'  ,'1/1/18 15:12', 9.08,'Jane')
> , ('1/2/18','Alice','1/2/18 13:45',13.15,'Jane')
> , ('1/2/18','Bob'  ,'1/2/18 15:57', 6.00,'Tarzan')
> , ('1/2/18','Carol','1/2/18 13:13', 6.00,'Tarzan')
> ;
> ```

The suggested query is this:

> ```
> select
>     *
> from (
>     select
>         *
>         , case when hour(OrderTime) between 15 and 18 then 
>                 row_number() over(partition by `Date`, customer
>                                       order by MaxPrice DESC)
>                 else null 
>           end rn
>     from mytable
>     ) d
> where rn = 1
> ;
> ```

and the result will give access to all columns you include in the derived table.

> ```
> Date       | Customer | OrderTime           | MaxPrice | Bartender | rn
> :--------- | :------- | :------------------ | -------: | :-------- | -:
> 0001-01-18 | Bob      | 0001-01-18 15:12:00 |     9.08 | Jane      |  1
> 0001-02-18 | Bob      | 0001-02-18 15:57:00 |     6.00 | Tarzan    |  1
> ```

To help display how this works, running the derived table subquery:

> ```
> select
> *
> , case when hour(OrderTime) between 15 and 18 then 
>         row_number() over(partition by `Date`, customer order by MaxPrice DESC)
>         else null 
>   end rn
> from mytable
> ;
> ```

produces this interim resultset:

> ```
> Date       | Customer | OrderTime           | MaxPrice | Bartender |   rn
> :--------- | :------- | :------------------ | -------: | :-------- | ---:
> 0001-01-18 | Alice    | 0001-01-18 13:45:00 |    13.15 | Jane      | null
> 0001-01-18 | Bob      | 0001-01-18 15:12:00 |     9.08 | Jane      |    1
> 0001-02-18 | Alice    | 0001-02-18 13:45:00 |    13.15 | Jane      | null
> 0001-02-18 | Bob      | 0001-02-18 15:57:00 |     6.00 | Tarzan    |    1
> 0001-02-18 | Carol    | 0001-02-18 13:13:00 |     6.00 | Tarzan    | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c05cd6fd881a041f69c2adcfa02c47c3)*